# Complex functions and conjugation

Tags: complex-analysis

if z is a complex function, is $z \times |z|^2 = |z|^3$? If not then is $\bar{z} \times |z|^2 = |z|^3$?

Comment: $|z|^3=(z\bar{z})^3=z\bar{z}|z|^2$.

Comment: thanks, then it is a no, right?

Comment: @DiegoMath: $z\bar{z} = |z|^2$

Comment: Did you try an example like $z=1+i$?

Comment: now i did, it didnt work... is that correct? @user7530

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the formulas hold true in general. In fact, they only hold true if $z$ is nonneagtive. If $z = 0$, their is nothing to prove. If $z\neq 0$, then the equations reduce to $z = |z|$ and $\bar{z} = |z|$. Taking the conjugate of the latter equation results in $z = |z|$. Since $|z|$ is nonegative and $z = |z|$, we must have that $z$ is nonnegative.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by nonnegative? We have that z is a complex function. Can a function be nonnegative? Can we assure that it is.. Please note that many times z appeared in log(z), and we know for this to make sense, everything inside log must be positive or am I mistaken? Can this help us figure out what z is?

Comment: I thought $z$ was supposed to represent a complex number, but it doesn't change things. The point is $|z|$ is a (nonnegative) real number for every complex function $z$, i.e., if $z = z(w)$ is a complex function, $|z(w)|$ is nonnegative for every $w \in \Bbb C$. If $z|z| = |z|^2$, then for every $w\in \Bbb C$, $z(w) = 0$ or $z(w)\neq 0$ and $z(w) = |z(w)|$. So $z$ takes values in $[0,\infty)$, which is what is means for $z$ to be nonnegative.